# Use custom Rails helper in ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

We have a helper method that we use to generate URLs in views and in an SMS that's being sent through an ActiveJob.

How can we access the helper method in the job?

```
module Crew::AvailableJobsHelper
  def accept_url(cleaner, occurrence)
    if some_condition_is_true
      crew_accept_job_url(cleaner_id: cleaner.id, job_id: occurrence.job.id)        
    else
      crew_accept_occurrence_url(cleaner_id: current_user.id, occurrence_id: occurrence.id)
    end
  end
end

class Crew::UnassignedAlertJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    sms_body = "Click here to accept a job: #{accept_url(cleaner, occurrence)}"
  end
end
```

Comment: try this #{ApplicationController.helpers.accept_url(cleaner, occurrence)}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me

```
ApplicationController.helpers.accept_url(cleaner, occurrence)
```

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.